# JSV Schema Validation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, schema

Is it possible to store JSV inside MongoDB with schemas for each collection then run MapReduce to validate documents? Inserting the invalid documents into a collection I can manually fix up?

I want as little external application intervention as possible, ideally a cron that MapReduces over dirty documents each day then I will investigate why these documents are invalid manually.

Comment: Did you end up working out a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Map/Reduce probably isn't the right approach for checking schema compliance as it doesn't modify the documents in the original collection.  As such you can't set a flag in the document indicating that it has been validated and may end up revalidating with each cron run.

Suggested approach:

- Add an indexed `validated` field to your documents; perhaps this would be a numeric value if you want to version your schemas.
- If possible all documents should be validated on insertion
- Write a script which will find all documents that have not been validated to match the current schema and update the `validated` field based on the JSV outcome
- Save the specific validation errors into another collection or possibly a subdocument (you may want to consider some [manual padding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Padding+Factor#PaddingFactor-ManualPadding) if the addition of error reports ends up triggering excessive document moves).